# What are the powers of Monica Rambeau?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In the web series *WandaVision* when Monica Rambeau enters the Hex her cells are rewritten at molecular level after which she gains some powers. What are these powers which she possesses?

Comment: https://nerdist.com/article/monica-rambeau-superpowers-explained-wandavision/

Comment: Seem to be consistent with her comic book powers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Rambeau

Comment: She has the power to kill a franchise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monica Rambeau reveals in *The Marvels* (2023 film) that she has the ability to manipulate and see all wavelengths of the electromagnetic spectrum. As shown in the film, this gives her a variety of powers, such as seeing energy emanating from its source, phasing through matter or energy, shooting energy blasts or punching with energy-charged fists, flying, becoming invisible, absorbing energy, and releasing the absorbed energy.

###### Seeing energy emanating from a source

[image] [image]

###### Phasing through matter or energy

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

###### Shooting energy blasts or punching with energy-charged fists

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

###### Flying

[image] [image] [image]

###### Becoming invisible

[image] [image]

###### Absorbing energy

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: I think they need to upgrade their technobabble.  Manipulation of all quantum fields is a superpower.  All wavelengths of the electromagnetic spectrum is just a lightshow.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: Well, it does include a fair amount on non-visible but useful things like heat (infrared), microwave, and gamma rays. Her Marvel entry mentions "visible light, radio waves, electricity, X-rays, microwaves, infrared radiation, ultraviolet radiation, cosmic rays, gamma radiation, and a wide variety of high-power lasers" among things she can manipulate.

Answer (score 12):

We only get a very brief glimpse into the powers but so far we've seen:

When Monica enters for the final time and receives her powers we initially see the world through her eyes. It shows that the world is a purple-ish colour but also that there are waves of energy around power lines and the like showing she can see electromagnetic energy now.

[image: View through Monica's altered eyes of the world in electromagnetic vision showing a purpleish colour]

She is next shown to have energy absorption. After entering again and confronting Wanda they have a brief to-do which ends in Wanda throwing Monica onto the street. Instead of landing in a big pile, Monica does a *"Super-hero landing!"* and blue energy surrounds her limbs absorbing the impact.

[image: Monica lands (superhero landing!) on the street and her limbs are encompassed with a blue energy glow]

Lastly, Monica puts herself in between the twins and Hayward who is firing at them. As she does so the bullets hit her and enter but seem to slow down and phase through, in a similar fashion to Vision's phasing.

[image: Shot of the bullets phasing through Monica's body]

We've not seen anything else in the brief time we see her with powers and they mostly seemed to happen instinctively at this point. Presumably later on in the MCU as she learns about them she'll get a greater understanding and control and will be able to do more things.